# Vue.js component loads before axios.get()

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-props

I have the following component with a prop called objects

```
<Table :objects="orders"/>
```

And in `mounted()` I have an axios.get() that fetches data from Directus CMS that looks like this.

```
this.orders = await this.axios.get('url')
    .then(response => {
        return response.data.data;
     });
```

I get an error in my table component saying that the `objects` prop is null or undefined, but in Vue Devtools it has some objects in it. I tried making the axios.get() in the `beforeCreated()` but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that `this.orders` is an array of objects. In that case, you can simply use v-if on Table to mount the component only when this.orders contains some items.

```
<Table v-if="orders.length" :objects="orders"/>
```

You could also define the default value for prop `objects`: this way it won't be null even if the data is missing.

```
// Inside Table component
objects: {
  type: Array,
  required: false,
  default: () => [], // default value is an empty array
},
```

Comment: I wasted so much time with this, and the solution was so simple.

Comment: Actually it doesn't work. It only shows me the table with 1 row.

Comment: What kind of value is stored in this.orders?

Comment: orders is an array with json objects

Comment: Then it should work. Have you tried console.log(this.objects)  inside the Table component's mounted() ? You can also create a watcher and console.log the value as it changes.
If you share Table's component in your original post I might help, but the code above should do the job, so you probably have a bug somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

mounted lifecycle method happens after the component has been mounted, aka when DOM tree has already been created.

What you're looking for is beforeMount method, which is called after the component has finished setting up reactive state, but DOM nodes haven't been created yet.

If you call your endpoint inside beforeMount method and await for results, your component will render when the data already exists, on condition that no error was returned.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using the data object 'orders' for your axios call. I'm assuming you are using the Options API due to your usage of 'this', otherwise I would suggest using ref() or reactive() to update the DOM. In your case, the content is rendering faster than the network response, which is why it shows undefined. You would need to fire your request in a 'beforeRouteEnter()' hook, not 'beforeCreated'.

Consider using this example instead...

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      orders: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async getOrders() {
      const response = await axios.get("url");
      this.orders = response.data.data;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getOrders();
  },
};
```